# Why does my router get kicked off network?

Tags: switch, router, ipv4, dhcp

My network has a server that does DHCP, and I have a switch that connects multiple computers. Currently I have a wireless backup solution that works subpar and I would like to get ADSL up and running.

When I plug the router into the network I cannot ping its ip address, however when I directly plug my pc into the router I can ping its ip. Usually it works for less than 5 minutes on the network before I lose internet connection, and cannot ping the router anymore.

Am I overlooking something simple, or is more info required?

I tested with multiple ports and network cables.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Network Diagram]

EDIT:

A new router was installed on the network which gave out DHCP which I was not taking into consideration. This caused my issue.

Comment: A simple diagram and the model of your router would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry but home network questions are not on-topic on this stack exchange. See http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You could probably ask this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Sebastian I initially wanted to ask this on superuser, however I thought since this is about network infrastructure and why network protocols clash or don't work I thought this site might be more relevant.

Comment: Is your router also doing DHCP? Two DHCP servers could cause trouble...

Comment: @Sebastian "On-topic: Enterprise or Service Provider Networks
Questions one would encounter while operating, maintaining, purchasing, or managing an enterprise / service provider network. The question should be about the operation of your own network." How is this not exactly applicable to my question?

Comment: @Nightwolf Look at the "What types of questions are explicitly OFF-topic?" section of the help page. Your network is a consumer/home network. Even if this is a small office network, you are customer of a service provider which makes this appropriate for Superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new DSL router/modem has 2 interfaces - LAN and WAN.  Out of the box, it is likely providing DHCP services on to the LAN (serving up IP addresses).  You need to log in to the management GUI on that new DSL router and turn this off.  You then need to assign a static IP address to the LAN interface - an address that is on the subnet/VLAN switchport that it plugs into.

Then, the new DSL router needs to be told of the other private IP address subnets that exist on your network so that devices on other subnets can be reached by the new DSL router.  This is probably as easy as adding routes to the routing table telling it that these are reachable via the primary gateways IP address.

Now, how to handle the switching of the default gateway between primary and secondary (new DSL router) if primary WAN is down.  That is doable in a number of standards-based ways but alot of times your gateway will have some proprietary method of doing this.  It can be simple of very complex config becuase remember, sometimes a primary WAN outage is NOT accompanied by a link outage.  You want to research alternate routing, failover routing in the devices documentation to get sample configs.  Or, post the device make/model here.

Comment: Your answer made me realize that I had a new router installed while I was away from the office which I completely forgot about. And obviously as you mentioned the new router had DHCP services set up out of the box.